# How to use ngResource when server is on a different localhost?

Tags: angularjs, express, ionic-framework, mean-stack, ngresource

I am building an app with Ionic and MEAN stack. My express server is running on localhost:3000 while my Ionic public code is running on localhost:8100. From my research, it seems like Ionic can run on a different IP address from the server and should just use ngResource to send $http requests.

So I have a RESTful endpoint like this in server.js

```
router.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.json({"name":"Abdul"});
});
```

And on the Ionic client code I am sending in a request like this:

```
app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope, $resource){
    $scope.test = $resource('localhost:3000/');
    $scope.test_button = function(){
        console.log($scope.test);
    }
});
```

But when I click the `test_button`, instead of `[{"name":"Abdul"}]` being logged in the console, I get the following null message:

```
function Resource(value) {
     shallowClearAndCopy(value || {}, this);
}
```

Can anyone help me out on connecting the client and server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$resource` object will only create an object with having `get`, `save`, `update`, etc. So for calling get method of server, you need to call `get` method of $resource object. That method will return `$promise` object will provide a promise. On which you can place `.then` promise, in which you will get data in success function.

One more thing is, when you are returning data from the server, you are returning object in array format. So in that case you need to specify `get` method will return array by having `isArray: true` option there.

```
$scope.test = $resource('http://localhost:3000/', {}, {get: { isArray: true}});
$scope.test.get().$promise.then(function(data){ //success function
   $scope.test = data;
},function(error){ //error function
   console.log(error);
})
```

---

to make your application more better, you could move up your `$resource` object to `service/factory` to make that call reusable.

```
app.service('dataService', function($resource){
   var resourceUrl = $resource('http://localhost:3000/', {}, {get: { isArray: true} });
   this.getData = function(){
      return resourceUrl.get().$promise;
   };
})
```

**Controller**

```
app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope, dataService){
    $scope.test_button = function(){
       dataService.getData().then(function(data){ //success function
           $scope.test = data;
       },function(error){ //error function
           console.log(error);
       })
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Pankaj, thanks for the reply! I am confused with this code here. Where do I put $resource? I am getting an error `Cannot read property 'get' of undefined`

Comment: Thank you Pankaj but I still have `Cannot read property 'get' of undefined` error. I have added the ngResource module. Shouldn't the `$scope.test.get()...` code above at least have some reference to `$resource`?

Comment: @KangzeHuang you don't need to remove `$scope.test = $resource(localhost:3000/)` code from your controller. look at edit..will fix the issue

Comment: I fixed one of my mistakes. The reference to localhost:3000 should have been in quotations. I copied over your code and I am getting a different response... an object with `data: null`. But making progress! :) Am I on the right track?

Comment: As well as an error `XMLHttpRequest cannot load localhost:3000. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.`

Comment: @KangzeHuang now you need to enable CORS on server side.. I thought you had it there. :)

Comment: I thought I did too. My server code has `app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});`. Do you think the CORS is the main obstacle here or perhaps I have another error somewhere?

Comment: @KangzeHuang I think you are stucked up on CORS stuff. do it first.

Comment: Ok, thanks Pankaj for your help! I will come back to this issue after dealing with CORS. :) Cheers from Canada (its 6:30am here)

Comment: I found the error! I changed `$resource('localhost:3000/');` to `$resource('http://localhost:3000/');` and it worked. Thanks for all the help Pankaj!

Comment: @KangzeHuang Oh.. I missed that.. Thanks :) Glad to help.. thanks :)